# Why do these two graphs have the same shape?

Tags: python

I want to transform the graph.

But, apparently the list has changed since "list3 = rdp(list2, epsilon=0.5)", but the shape ot the graph is the same.

Why is this?

I tried like this.

````
from rdp import rdp
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

list1 = [278.966,713.891,290.003,714.811,298.281,715.731,319.435,717.571,332.312,721.251,344.268,723.091,356.225,725.851,384.737,731.371,395.774,734.131,409.57,734.131,421.527,734.131,435.323,734.131,444.521,730.451,450.039,725.851,462.915,722.171,470.273,721.251,477.631,721.251,510.742,724.011,521.779,724.011,536.495,725.851,543.853,727.691,553.051,733.211,556.729,735.051,560.408,738.73,570.526,742.41,581.563,746.09,597.198,749.77,623.871,750.69,651.463,732.291,655.142,729.531,663.42,726.771,681.815,727.691,700.21,731.371,707.568,733.211,717.685,734.131,730.561,735.051,739.759,735.051,746.197,734.131,754.475,728.611,762.752,719.411,771.95,701.932,773.789,690.892,776.549,672.493,776.549,663.293,779.308,648.574,781.147,637.534,781.147,632.935,778.388,577.737,775.629,555.658,774.709,550.138,772.87,541.858,772.87,533.579,772.87,521.619,771.95,503.22,770.11,488.5,769.191,482.061,769.191,473.781,769.191,457.222,772.87,437.902,775.629,422.263,779.308,406.624,783.907,391.904,788.505,376.265,791.265,367.985,797.703,329.347,758.154,313.707,740.679,310.028,727.802,303.588,718.605,298.988,704.808,294.388,690.093,289.788,666.179,291.628,653.303,298.988,639.507,305.428,630.309,305.428,622.951,303.588,607.315,298.988,601.797,290.708,607.315,270.469,608.235,260.35,609.155,247.47,610.075,232.751,610.075,222.631,610.075,209.752,607.315,200.552,604.556,195.952,591.68,188.592,577.884,186.753,563.168,184.913,550.291,183.073,542.933,182.153,525.458,180.313,509.822,180.313,501.545,181.233,484.07,182.153,466.594,183.073,459.236,185.833,452.798,186.753,445.44,190.432,441.761,193.192,439.002,196.872,435.323,213.431,434.403,219.871,434.403,229.071,438.082,253.91,439.002,261.27,445.44,276.909,448.2,285.189,448.2,287.948,439.922,301.748,402.212,303.588,394.854,307.268,382.898,315.547,372.78,318.307,368.182,316.467,358.065,312.787,347.028,301.748,328.633,300.828,314.837,300.828,304.719,300.828,289.084,299.908,281.726,298.988,276.207,299.908,268.849,301.748,257.812,316.467,254.133,330.267,254.133,338.546,254.133,350.506,254.133,355.106,247.695,371.665,243.096,385.465,243.096,402.024,243.096,407.544,244.936,421.343,247.695,429.623,249.535,442.502,251.374,454.462,251.374,467.341,251.374,474.701,250.454,482.061,247.695,492.18,242.177,509.66,241.257,524.379,243.096,537.259,248.615,551.058,253.214,558.418,256.893,563.937,260.572,573.137,264.251,584.177,266.09,592.456,266.09,603.496,267.93,617.295,268.849,624.655,267.93,634.775,264.251,648.574,261.491,656.854,257.812,666.053,251.374,673.413,247.695,681.693,246.775,692.732,252.294,705.612,255.16,706.532,263.331,713.891,268.849,713.891,278.966,713.891]
X = list1[::2] # Elements from list1 starting from 1 iterating by 2
Y = list1[1::2] # Elements from list1 starting from 0 iterating by 2
# print(X)
# print(Y)
list2 = []
for i in range(len(X)):
    list2.append([X[i],Y[i]])

print(list2)

plt.plot(X, Y)

list3 = rdp(list2, epsilon=0.5)

A = []
B = []
for i in range(len(list3)):
    A.append(list3[i][0])
    B.append(list3[i][1])
    

plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
orig_graph = plt.plot(A, B)
plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
rdp_graph = plt.plot(X, Y)
plt.show()```
````

Answer (score 0):

On the graph, the eye does not see the change due to the scale. Set `epsilon=5` and it will be more noticeable. And so you can see the work of the algorithm to reduce the length of the list.

```
plt.plot(X, Y)
list3 = rdp(list2, epsilon=0.5)
print(len(list2), len(list3))
----------------------
165 112


plt.plot(X, Y)
list3 = rdp(list2, epsilon=5)
print(len(list2), len(list3))
----------------------
165 40
```

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of RDP is to provide a curve that looks similar but has fewer points. You can't see the difference because it is preserving the shape effectively, as it is supposed to. You can see this simply by adding `"."` so that `plot` draws the points instead of only the line.

```
shape = np.array(list1).reshape((-1, 2))
rdp_shape = rdp(shape, epsilon=0.5)
plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
orig_graph = plt.plot(*shape.T, ".")
plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
rdp_graph = plt.plot(*rdp_shape.T, ".")
plt.show()
```